# Symfony issue - Registration form

Tags: symfony-forms

I have an issue on my Symfony web code. I'm a beginner and I would make a simple registration form so I generated this form with the following command :"make:registration-form" after create a user entity (as describe on the symfony documentation). My registrationController file works fine and I can create users through the register twig template. So, I know that I have no problem to send values on my database.
My issue is I need to create my form on my main template (not in the register template that I created just for the test). My problem is when I submit my form, there is no values send to my database. I see no error when I submit and I don't understant why on my register template, I can send my form on my data-base and it won't works on my main template.

This is my main template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/app.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/app-login.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/transition.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
{% block body %}
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="{{ path('main_index') }}"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Idyl" class="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="{{ path('app_devtool') }}"><font color="#ff8a00">Devtools</font></a>
            </li>
            <li class="search">
                <a href="{{ path('lucky_number') }}">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                </a>
            </li>                      
            {% if app.user %}
            <li class="pseudo">
                <a href="{{ path('app_user') }}"><font color="#00ffb6">{{ app.user.username }}</font></a>
            </li>           
            {% else %}
            <div class="btn-log">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="btnLogin-popup">Login</a>
            </li>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <li class="hamburger">
                <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>

<!-- Login -->

    <center>
        <div class="wrapper active">
            <span class="icon-close">
                <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
            </span>
            <div class="form-box log">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <!-- <img src="img/design1/jarrex-mini.png" alt="Idyl" class="logo"> -->
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="input-inbox">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon 
                        name="person-circle"></ion-icon>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" required>
                        <label for="inputUsername">Username</label>                 
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-inbox">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon 
                        name="lock-closed"></ion-icon>
                        </span>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" required>
                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="remember-forgot">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"><font color="#fff"> Remember me</font></label>
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>                         
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
                    <div class="log-register">
                        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#" class="register-link"><font color="#fff">Register</font></a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

<!-- Registration -->

            <div class="form-box register">
                <h2>Registration</h2>
                <form method="post">                    
                    <div class="input-inbox">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon 
                        name="log-in-outline"></ion-icon>
                        </span>
                        <input name="{{ field_name(registrationForm.username) }}"
                            value="{{ field_value(registrationForm.username) }}"                            
                            class="form-control" type="text" required>                  
                        <label>Username</label>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-inbox">
                        <span class="icon"><ion-icon 
                        name="lock-closed"></ion-icon>
                        </span>
                        <input name="{{ field_name(registrationForm.plainPassword) }}"
                            value="{{ field_value(registrationForm.plainPassword) }}"                           
                            class="form-control" type="password" required>                  
                        <label>Password</label>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="remember-forgot">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"><font color="#fff"> agree to the terms & conditions</font></label>    
                    </div>                  
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
                    <div class="log-register">
                        <p>Already have an account? <a href="#" class="login-link"><font color="#fff">Login</font></a></p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <!-- Page principale -->
    </div>
    <div class="vignette"></div> 
    <img src="img/main/work01/bckimg.png" data-speedx="0.1" data-speedy="0.01" 
    data-speedz="0"  
        data-distance="-200" class="parallax bg-img">
    <img src="img/main/work01/02.png" data-speedx="0.05" data-speedy="0.32" 
    data-speedz="0.15" 
        data-distance="850" class="parallax pht02">
    <img src="img/main/work01/03.png" data-speedx="0.1" data-speedy="0.125" 
    data-speedz="0.05"  
        data-distance="1400" class="parallax pht03">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/main/work01/04.png" data-speedx="0.05" data-speedy="0.05" 
    data-speedz="3" 
        data-distance="700" class="parallax pht04"></a>
    <img src="img/main/work01/05.png" data-speedx="0.07" data-speedy="0.05" 
    data-speedz="3" 
        data-distance="2600" class="parallax pht05">
    <img src="img/main/work01/06.png" data-speedx="0.1" data-speedy="0.1" 
    data-speedz="4" 
        data-distance="2500" class="parallax pht06">
    <img src="img/main/work01/07.png" data-speedx="0.2" data-speedy="0.112" 
    data-speedz="0.2" 
        data-distance="4000" class="parallax pht07">        
</main>
<!-- 2ème page -->
<div class="block-1">
    This is a test
    {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <center><p>Pseudo: {{ app.user.username }}</p></center>
    {% endif %}
    <br/><br/><br/>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('build/css/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/css/dsgn1.js') }}"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

This is my MainController :

<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{

    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->redirectToRoute('main_index');
        }

        return $this->render('main/main.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

}
```

This is my route.yaml file :

```
`
controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

utilisateurs_index:
    path: /utilisateurs
    # the controller value has the format 'controller_class::method_name'
    controller: App\Controller\UtilisateursController::index

lucky_number:
    path: lucky/number
    # the controller value has the format 'controller_class::method_name'
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
    
blog_show:
    path: /blog/{id}
    # the controller value has the format 'controller_class::method_name'
    controller: App\Controller\BlogController::show

main_index:
    path: /
    # the controller value has the format 'controller_class::method_name'
    controller: App\Controller\MainController::register

app_register:
    path: /register
    controller: App\Controller\RegistrationController::register

app_login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login

app_user:
    path: /utilisateurs
    controller: App\Controller\UtilisateursController::index

app_devtool:
    path: /devtool
    controller: App\Controller\DevtoolController::index`
```

This my registrationFormType file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?

I want to use my main template to send my registration form to my database.